# What's the safest way to check if a number of unknown type is 0? AKA Why float(0) is not equal to (int)0?

Tags: php, floating-point, comparison

Can someone help me understand why this happens?

```
$zero = (float)0;
var_dump($zero);
var_dump(0);
var_dump( ($zero === 0) );
```

This produces:

```
float(0)
int(0)
bool(false)
```

I don't really understand why, I am aware of the giant red warning [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), but isn't 0 supposed to be 0? Or is PHP actually comparing the variable type (float against int)?

Assuming that's the case, what is the safest way to check if a number (not knowing its exact type) is 0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(0)` is same as `float(0)`, just that when you use `===` then type, as well as value, is compared. In this case value is same but type is different, hence its `false`. 
Those values are `Equal` but not `Identical`.

```
int(0) == float(0)    // true because only value is compared, which is same.
int(0) === float (0)  // false because even though value is same, type is also compared, which is different
```

> $a === $b 'Identical' TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
>   $a == $b  'Equal' TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.

[Reference:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

A good way to test whether numeric value of your variable is 0 would be:

```
if (intval($zero)==0)
{
  // $zero is 0 in numeric terms. You can even send it a string to test, which will be 0
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

=== compares type as well as value. If you just want to compare value then use ==

```
$zero = (float)0;
var_dump($zero);
var_dump(0);
var_dump( ($zero === 0) );
var_dump( ($zero == 0) );
```

Will return 
float(0) 
int(0) 
bool(false) 
bool(true)

Answer (score 0):

it's because === compares types and value and == compares only values

```
$foo = 0;

var_dump((float)$foo==(int)$foo); //Produces true

var_dump((float)$foo===(int)$foo); //Produces false
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually their are two comparative operators

==   checks only for equality of values

===  checks the equality of both type and the value.